# CSS Positioning not displaying as expected

Tags: css, html, positioning

I thought I was getting the hang of CSS and had finally conquered positioning! Well I had until I tested my site locally on my ipad!

Using the below example I just want the background to be black (done no problem). On top of the black background I want the green "content-background" to run across the whole screen from left to right (100%) above the black background. On top of the green "content-background" I want the main-container div. I am not sure why but my example is not working? This should be a simple thing to do??? The problem is noticeable when the browser is shrunk from say right to left and then the scroll horizontal scroll bar is moved to the right. When this happens you will see that the green "content-background" does not expand vertically across the whole screen???

Any help is greatly appreciated  : )

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Margate/Sk5X9/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<title>Positioning</title>

<style type="text/css">     
#page-background{background-color:black; }  
#content-background{position:absolute; top: 100px; width: 100%; height: 616px; background-color: green;}
#main-container{position: relative; top: 0px; width: 1000px; height: 910px; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px solid red;}
</style>
</head>

<body id="page-background">

<div id="content-background"></div>
<div id="main-container">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code is not complete. proballay an copy/paste oversight

Comment: Hello Jawad, I just checked the code and everything is correct? If you go to the fiddle you may be able to get a better idea. The page is totally basic but does show the problem. It intentionally has no content because there was no need to include everything.... There is a problem I think with the positioning but I am not sure why? Thank you for any help.  :  )

Comment: right. my bad. looking it up now

Comment: in the mean time you should check this out - http://www.brainjar.com/css/positioning/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your fiddle and fiddled with it a little bit to get the desired effect that you had mentioned.

without modifying the HTML here is the new CSS

```
#page-background {
    background-color:black;
    width: 100%;
}
#content-background {

    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 616px;
    background-color: green;
}
#main-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 910px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

I find that specifying the body width to 100% gives the child divs a proper reference to the screen size and allows the child DIV ( content-background ) to span the length of the screen.

** because the DIV is no longer "absolute" positioned the top, left, bottom and right properties will do nothing. instead use margins to move stuff around.

as for the border DIV  -- because it is after the ( content-background ) Div -- putting this in relative positioning will place it after the ( content-background ) DIV  -- by specifying this Div as "absolute" you can place it anywhere on the screen provided you set the top, left, bottom and right properties.

I hope this helps guide you in the right direction for future css usage as there are about a million ways that this example can be written     :)

Comment: ignore the relative comment    The element is positioned relative to its normal position, so "left:20" adds 20 pixels to the element's LEFT position not sets left to 20

Comment: Hi Dave, Thank you very much for your time and help. Great help for me. I will go back to the CSS positioning drawing board! I thought I had it cracked but now realize I simply only understand the very basics (I think!). Positioning is fundamental and I find it so confusing to master! Margate...

Comment: glad i could help !      ive been fighting the positioning monster for a good year now and all i can give for advice is keep at it and eventually it will all click :D